# How to read non english (Tamil language) fonts using BufferedReader in Java while the file works fine in MacOS, but not in Windows?

Tags: java, unicode, ascii, bufferedreader, unicode-string

Right now I read the Tamil fonts using following code

```
BufferedReader tamil = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "Copy1.txt"));
            StringBuffer Tamil_T = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer each_T = new StringBuffer();
while ((EachLine = tamil.readLine()) != null) {

                int i = 0;
                StringBuffer eachWord = new StringBuffer();

                for (; i < tamilEachLine.length(); i++) {
                    if (i >= 27) { 

                        if (tamilEachLine.charAt(i) != ' '
                                || i == tamilEachLine.length() - 1) { 

                            eachWord.append(tamilEachLine.charAt(i));

                        } else if (tamilEachLine.charAt(i) == ' ') { 
                            each_T.append(eachTamilWord);

                            each_T.append("%20"); 
                            eachWord = new StringBuffer();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Don't worry about the code logic or variables as this piece of code is a part of large code chunk.

The code works fine when the input file is in Mac OS and the code run in Eclipse IDE in Mac OS, but it doesn't work when used in Windows in Eclipse IDE

If I use

```
BufferedReader tamil = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "Copy1.txt"), "utf-8");
```

all I get is ??????.....????

I tried `cp1252, utf-16, utf-32` as well. Nothing works so far in Windows OS.

The sample font in input file will looks like this

"என் பெயர் ராமு சோமு"

Comment: Tamil is not a **font**. It's a human language that can be written down. Now, text files read by a `java.io.Reader` needs a **charset** so you must know the one used to encode `Copy1.txt`. Is this file written by a human? Downloaded from the Internet? Is it intended to me modified or is immutable? You need to upload the original file somewhere (best zipped to be sure is not transcoded by anyone) and then tell how that file is supposed to get on the Windows and Mac machines

Comment: The input file is given by my friend, and I copied few lines from that file to a new file in Mac and things were working fine. The same file was emailed to the Windows system and there few lines were added and saved before using. How to find out encoding of a file? I don't get this part "You need to upload the original file somewhere (best zipped to be sure is not transcoded by anyone) and then tell how that file is supposed to get on the Windows and Mac machines". You mean to say you want me to upload the file for viewers here to take a look at it?